# Passing data from view to action ?? Solution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send the user id (integer) from a view to the action. If I pass it using routevalues object, the user id will be visible in the browser address bar. 
       How can I pass user id from view to the action without using aforementioned method??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hidden input element inside a form. You should generally use POST, not GET (i.e. use a form, not an a href) for anything that is changing data in your system.

Comment: +1; but it is just so darned **funny** when google deletes all your data when crawling the links on your site ;-p

Answer (score 1):

The user id is commonly inferred from your authentication mechanism (cookie etc), so for the *current* user you shouldn't need to pass it around.

The main time you *would* include this in the request is when the page being displayed *relates* to users - and in particular where you (or an admin) want to browse other users records - then you might use "/users/current/orders" (use the cookie) or "/users/12345/orders" (and you should verify permission to browse 12345).

Note that if you use /current/ or similar, you should ensure it isn't cached between different users - so in many ways it is simpler to just show the user-id and to heck with the url; just go for the simple "/users/12345/orders" case.

What is the scenario here?

Comment: There is a list of friends on the page and after clicking "Remove" link, that userid(friend id) should be passed to the action.
I tried viewdata but since i'm using foreach() loop, I'm getting the error as "Item with that name is already added to viewdata".